# udp multicast on network

Tags: networking, streaming

I'm aware that this is a noob question. But I'm hoping some kind soul have time to tell me if I'm thinking wrong. My terminology is probably confusing but I hope that my question is understandable.

I want to stream a live video stream to a couple of computers on a LAN and thinking of doing this with udp multicast. But I'm not sure about what capacity the sending computer needs to have when sending on multicast.

I have been able to stream to one machine. Does this mean that I can multicast to any other machine on the network without need to beef up the sending computer?

As I understand multicast it is sending on the multicast address and therefore only needs to send the stream once...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, multicast sends packets once. Your LAN must be able to forward multicasts, if you've a more complex LAN. Receiving computers must "subscribe" to the multicast group(s) they are interested in, so LAN switches etc. know where they should forward packets to. Many switches/routers do that out of the box.

Sending out a multicast stream isn't particularly taxing for modern computers, and the numbers of receivers doesn't matter. So you probably don't need a better sending computer.

There's open source software like [Icecast](http://icecast.org/) which isn't that difficult to use.

Comment: Thank you! And also thank you for the tip about Icecast. I will check it out.